# Targeting the first element of each tag within a nested tag n times

Tags: html, css

I'm using the following css code, its working fine but i'd like to not color anymore elements 
after 'tue 7-1-1'. is there a way the stop the nth-child after a certain point?

I'm not allowed to touch the code, only allowed to use css to manipulate the first child of every element up until a certain point.

ps: span elements are nested.

```css
span:nth-child(1) {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<section id="tue" class="t">
  <h2>Tuesday</h2>
  <span>tue-1</span>
  <span>tue-7</span>
  <div>
    <span>tue-7-1</span>
    <div>
      <span>tue-7-1-1</span>
      <!-- end of target -->
      <span>tue-7-1-2</span>
    </div>
    <span>tue-7-2</span>
    <div>
      <span>tue-7-2-1</span>
      <div>
        <span>tue-7-2-1-1</span>
      </div>
      <span>tue-7-2-2</span>
</section>
```

Comment: You have 4 opening `div` tags in your code, but just two closing `div` tags.

Comment: Can you not just give all that you want to colour, a classname?

Comment: @Thomas you're right, i had to remove a big chunk of code in order to post this. Either way missing closing tags wont affect the initial problem here's a link to the full code if you're interested. http://jsfiddle.net/r8fz5ov1/30/

Comment: @putvande im not allowed to touch the code, only to use css to color the first child of every element up until a certain  point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this, some more specific CSS, but it will do the job.

```css
section > span:nth-child(1n+2),
section > div > span:first-child,
section > div > div:first-of-type > span:first-child {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<section id="tue" class="t">
  <h2>Tuesday</h2>
  <span>tue-1</span>
  <span>tue-7</span>
  <div>
    <span>tue-7-1</span>
    <div>
      <span>tue-7-1-1</span>
      <!-- end of target -->
      <span>tue-7-1-2</span>
    </div>
    <span>tue-7-2</span>
    <div>
      <span>tue-7-2-1</span>
      <div>
        <span>tue-7-2-1-1</span>
      </div>
      <span>tue-7-2-2</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Your solution proves to be solid, almost there. the code here is not complete, perhaps you could use the following link to find the full jsfiddle.net/r8fz5ov1/30 
Some of the first children of some div elements are still not selected.